# Is this problem worded correctly?

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm working on a problem from an old complex analysis prelim, but while doing so, I'm not sure about whether it is worded correctly.

The problem: Let $f(z)$ be a holomorphic function in the unit disk $\mathbb{D}$ that extends continuously to $\bar{\mathbb{D}}$ and $dA$ be area measure. Show that $$f(z)= \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{\bar{\mathbb{D}}} \frac{f(w) dA(w)}{(1- z \bar{w})^2}.$$ Shouldn't it be saying "extends continuously to $\partial \mathbb{D}$?" Isn't this integral being taken over $\partial \mathbb{D}$?

My thoughts/attempt: I think that I need to use the Cauchy Integral Formula $$f(z)= \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{\partial \mathbb{D}} \frac{f(w)dw}{w-z},$$ and need to manipulate it somehow to obtain the desired result.

Comment: I don't think that's misworded. To say that the function "extends continuously to $\partial \mathbb D$" wouldn't really make sense, since $\mathbb D$ does not lie in (or even intersect) $\partial \mathbb D$. Extension of a function generally comes up when you have a function $f$ defined on some set $A$, and a second set $A \subset B$. To extend the function $f$ to $B$ means that you find a function $g$ on $B$ so that $g|_A=f$. Note that, if $f$ is continuous on $\bar{\mathbb D}$, it's also continuous on $\partial \mathbb D$, and in a way that is compatible with $f|_\mathbb D$.

Comment: @MorganO: Thanks for clarifying. Seems CIF isn't doing the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the exercise is worded correctly. One often says that a continuous function $f$ defined on an open set "extends continuously to $\partial U$" when there is a continuous function $F\colon \overline{U} \to \mathbb{C}$ with $F\lvert_U = f$, but saying "$f$ extends continuously to $\overline{U}$" is at least as correct to describe that situation.

> Isn't this integral being taken over $\partial\mathbb{D}$?

No, the integral is taken over the unit disk (whether closed or open doesn't matter since the boundary is a null set).

Indeed, taking the integral formula

$$f(z) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\partial \mathbb{D}} \frac{f(w)}{w-z}\,dw = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\partial\mathbb{D}} \frac{f(w)\overline{w}}{1-\overline{w}z}\,dw,$$

and manipulating that to obtain the desired representation is the standard way. Note that $dA(w) = \frac{1}{2i} d\overline{w}\wedge dw$ and think of a theorem relating a boundary integral to an integral over the bounded domain.

Comment: Is the theorem you are asking me to think about Green's Theorem?

Comment: Have you seen $dx\wedge dy$ yet? (Actually, $dA = dx\wedge dy$ is a slight abuse of notation, but well, I hope writing the differential form makes it easier to find the pertinent theorem.)

Comment: If I knew which version of Stokes' theorem [the general one, by Cartan] is known as Green's, I could say yes or no. Probably it's Green's.

Comment: I'm still pretty much struggling with this problem. Just let me keep trying to see what I get.

Comment: If you have any experience with differential forms, I think using Stokes' theorem (the one by Cartan) is the simplest way.

Comment: I've added a hint how to set it up, in case you haven't found it yet.

Comment: Oh I see that factor of $\frac{1}{2i}$ in the differential form and the added hint alright.